# CakePHP Auth not re-logging in to the right path

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I am having some issues with the CakePHP Auth login. For some reason, instead of the site going to the path i have laid out for it, it looks at the form and goes right to the login function.

To explain, here is my code,

Router File :

```
Router::connect('/clientlogin', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'UsersLogin'));
Router::connect('/login', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
```

Pages Controller - UsersLogin Function :

```
 public function UsersLogin() {
   $this->render('/Pages/LoginForm');
 } //End of UsersLogin function
```

Users Controller - login Function :

```
   public function login() {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid Username Or Password, Please Try Again', 'default', array(), 'bad');
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
   } //End of Login function
```

LoginForm.cpt Code :

```
 echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
 echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url'=>'/login', 'id' => 'LoginForm')); 
 echo $this->Form->input('username');
 echo $this->Form->input('password');
 echo $this->Form->submit('Login', array('class' => 'Button'));
 echo $this->Form->end();
```

My main menu in my site has a 'login' button that points to '/clientlogin', which loads the form for my users to login with. However, when the session information expires, the areas of the site which require login to access them push me over to re-login.

But CakePHP is not going to /clientlogin its going to /login - which is not the form but the login controller. Also it dose not matter what I change it to but where ever I point my form is where Cake whats to go. For example, I changed the form to point to /mylogintest or /loginuser and Cake went to these paths instead.

So my main question is, when Cake needs to re auth the session information, how do I make sure it points to my clientform path and not the path laid out in my form.

If I have not been clear or, I have not posted something needed, then please ask me and I will try and fix it.

Many Thanks for any help given

Glenn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the default login action by passing extra keys into the components. See the code below :

```
// Pass settings in $components array
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'pages',
            'action' => 'UsersLogin'
        )
     )
 );
```

I am not sure why you need to create separate action to contain the login form. Usually I'll have the form inside the login action and check the request using $this->request->is('post'). See the Cookbook for more information http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

Comment: Many thanks, the request is('post') put me on the right track. I now only have one path in my route file pointing to the login function in my users controller and do an else check to render the form if the post check is not true, all seems to work go now.